# Using a conditional 'with' statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to process a large byte stream in Python. As far as I have read, using the 'with' statement prevents loading temporary data into memory which would be an advantage for me.

My problem is that I have two options to choose my source data stream from: a raw data stream or a source path.

```
if sourceRef:
    with open(sourceRef, 'rb') as ds:
        dstreams['master'] = self._generateMasterFile(ds)
else:
    with self._validate(source) as ds:
        dstreams['master'] = self._generateMasterFile(ds)
```

This works all right, but I have more complex scenarios where the operations following the 'with' satements are more complex and I don't want to duplicate them.

Is there a way to compact these two options?

Thank you,

gm

Edit: I'm using Python 3.

Comment: maybe make a method and pass the returned value to with to avoid writing numerous with statements

Comment: "Using the 'with' statement prevents loading temporary data into memory," doesn't sound like anything that I know the 'with' statement to do: its primary purpose is to automatically perform actions on the completion of the 'with' block (in the case of files, for example, exiting the block closes the file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest solution is probably to define `ds` beforehand:

```
if sourceRef:
    ds = open(sourceRef, 'rb')
else:
    ds = self._validate(source)

with ds:
    dstreams['master'] = self._generateMasterFile(ds)
```

This approach also works in a clean way when you have more than two possible `ds` values (you can simply extend the checks beforehand to determine the value for `ds`).

Comment: For some reason this does not work in Python 3:
`>>> var = b if b else a

>>> with var:

...     print(var)

...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: __exit__

`

Comment: @gattumarrudu see hlt's comment above, that's not related to Python 3.

Comment: But what happens when the code throws an exception between the `if` block and the `with` block? This code seems very fragile. (Of course, you are no worse off than having not used `with` at all.) Perhaps the better thing to do is wrap your `if` block in a function?

Comment: @BrandonHumpert: possibly, it seems that there always some time between opening the resource and entering the with block. So even when writing `with get_ds(sourceRef):` we'd get the possibility of an exception in between.

Comment: My real concern is that if someone goes back to maintain the code you've written here, there is a nonzero probability that other code might be inserted into the space between the `if` block and the `with` block.

Answer (score 6):

As long as both things work with `with` individually, you can inline the `if` statement as follows:

```
with (open(sourceRef, 'rb') if sourceRef else self._validate(source)) as ds:
    dstreams['master'] = self._generateMasterFile(ds)
```

Comment: It's not because of Python 3, it's because of the fact that each object used in `with` must define an `__exit__` method (which the object in the example you give in that comment does not have)